# Angular Object is possibly 'null'. Error at <span *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('emailAddr').hasError('required')">Enter email address</span>

Tags: angular11

Hi I am new to Angular 11 can anyone please help me with this error -
This is my code.

checkout.component.html

```
<h3>Checkout forms - Using Reactive forms</h3>
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="postData();">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="emailAddressField" formControlName="emailAddr">
          <span *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('emailAddr').hasError('required')">Enter email address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Quantity</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="passwordField" formControlName="quantity">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter Quantity</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="termsField" formControlName="terms">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Agree to Terms</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!checkoutForm.valid">Checkout</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am getting error as Error at <span *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('emailAddr').hasError('required')">Enter email address

checkout.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
  checkoutForm:FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

     this.checkoutForm = formBuilder.group({
      emailAddr: ['',Validators.required],
      quantity: ['',Validators.required],
      terms: ['',Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
  

  }

  
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  postData(){
    console.log(this.checkoutForm);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using**

```
<span *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('emailAddr').hasError('required')">Enter email address</span>
```

**Try**

```
<span *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('emailAddr')?.hasError('required')">Enter email address</span>
```

i have tested this code on my computer maybe it will also help you to resolve your compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf="cadastroForm.get('username')?.errors">`.

You have to use the `?`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is `cadastroForm`?